# MySQL - select row by Comparing two Columns

Tags: mysql, select

[image]

In the above table I have messages where 2 users can be the sender or receiver.

I need to find the most resent message (from one userid say 1000000172) from either situation (eg: sender_userid to receiver_userid ..or.. receiver_userid to sender_userid) and I'm struggling to write a SELECT query that can do that.

You will see in the image that both userid (members) have sent a message to each other. How can I select the most resent one. Remember there are many message between each of them.

I have tried the following query however it will return 2 messages where the user is the sender and receiver:

```
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime` 
FROM (
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime` FROM messages 
WHERE (receiver_userid='1000000172' OR sender_userid='1000000172') AND friendship_status=1 AND receiver_history=1
ORDER BY message_read DESC, `datetime` DESC
) AS MSG
GROUP BY receiver_userid;
```

Is there a way to only get one message that is the most resent between the 2 members?

Note: I query needs to get many messages for this member with other members - so the results would be one message (most resent) from this user with potentially 25 other members.

---

Final SELECT:

```
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime` 
FROM (
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime` FROM messages 
WHERE (receiver_userid='1000000172' OR sender_userid='1000000172') AND friendship_status=1 AND receiver_history=1
ORDER BY message_read DESC, `datetime` DESC
) AS MSG
GROUP BY (sender_userid AND receiver_userid);
```

Comment: you can order by date and limit the row result to 1. this way you will get one row.

Comment: the catch is I'm pulling the data for many conversations for this user. They could have 50 conversations with different members...

Comment: what about group by sender and receiver and getting the maximum date?

Comment: never tried that - like this: GROUP BY (sender_userid AND receiver_userid) ORDER BY `datetime`?

Comment: Please try, let me know... don't forget the `select max(dateTime) as time`

Comment: yes that works perfect... I will update the post to show what worked... thankyou so very much :) If you add below I will tick reply

Comment: I have added an answer, please except it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
Group by sender and reciever and then get maximum for the date-

```
select max(datetime) as time LIMIT 1
....
GROUP BY (sender_userid AND receiver_userid) ORDER BY datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I guess you made mistake.

### How your accepted query works

```
GROUP BY (sender_userid AND receiver_userid)
```

`sender_userid AND receiver_userid` is an expression which return 0 or 1, and in your case it would return 1 always because all `id`s are bigger than 0.

So, you are querying as follows

```
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime` 
FROM (
   ...
) AS MSG
GROUP BY 1
```

Preceding SQL is invalid even though it works for you.

### My suggestion

I think following query is right for you.

```
SELECT '1000000172' AS my_id, sender_userid, receiver_userid,
  message, message_read, `datetime` AS dt
FROM messages
WHERE (receiver_userid='1000000172' OR sender_userid='1000000172')
    AND friendship_status = 1
    AND receiver_history = 1
ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

`UNION` might be better if you have a lot of data. MySQL can't use INDEX when `col1 = xx OR col2 = xx` is executed even if `col1` and `col2` is INDEXed.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT '1000000172' AS my_id, sender_userid, receiver_userid,
      message, message_read, `datetime` AS dt
    FROM messages
    WHERE receiver_userid='1000000172'
        AND friendship_status = 1
        AND receiver_history = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1000000172' AS my_id, sender_userid, receiver_userid,
      message, message_read, `datetime` AS dt
    FROM messages
    WHERE sender_userid='1000000172')
        AND friendship_status = 1
        AND receiver_history = 1
) x
ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 1
```